# How to append data in struct model from second ViewController to first ViewController in swift ? and reload tableView that is present on firstVC?

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct, model, delegates

// I have a struct model for Notes

```
struct NotesModel{
    
    var groupName: String // sections in tableView
    var info: [NotesInfo] // rows in respective sections in tableView
    
}

struct NotesInfo{
    
    var groupName: String
    var image: String
    var notesTitle: String
    var notesDescription: String
    var notesDate: String
    
}


// 1) this is my ViewController(FirstVC)

var arrayNotes = [NotesModel]() // array that will be used to populate tableView
var info1 = [NotesInfo]()
var info2 = [NotesInfo]()
var info3 = [NotesInfo]()

// I have appended data in arrayNotes

info1.append(NotesInfo(groupName: "ABC", image: "img1", notesTitle: "Public Notes", notesDescription: "Public Notes are for xyz use...", notesDate: "17/08/2020"))

info1.append(NotesInfo(groupName: "ABC", image: "img1", notesTitle: "Public Notes(A)", notesDescription: "Public Notes are for xyz use...", notesDate: "19/08/2020"))
        
arrayNotes.append(NotesModel(groupName: "ABC", info: info1))

info2.append(NotesInfo(groupName: "XYZ", image: "img2", notesTitle: "My Notes", notesDescription: "My Notes include...", notesDate: "25/08/2020"))

arrayNotes.append(NotesModel(groupName: "XYZ", info: info2))        
        
info3.append(NotesInfo(groupName: "PQR", image: "img3", notesTitle: "Notes Example", notesDescription: "Notes Example here..", notesDate: "25/08/2020"))
       
arrayNotes.append(NotesModel(groupName: "PQR", info: info2))

// I have a TableView on ViewController to present NotesModel data

// MARK: - Number of Sections in TableView
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return arrayNotes.count // returns 3
        
    }


// MARK: - HeaderView in Section
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                
        let headerCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! HeaderCell
        
        let dict = arrayNotes[section]
        headerCell.lblGroupName.text = dict.groupName // "ABC", "XYZ", "PQR"

        let info = dict.info

        for values in  info{

            headerCell.imgGroup.image = UIImage(named: values.image) // "img1", "img2", "img3"
        }        
        return headerCell
        
    }

// MARK: - Number of Rows in TableView
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arrayNotes[section].info.count // "ABC" -> 2 rows, "XYZ" -> 1 row, "PQR" -> 1 row
    }

// MARK: - Cell For Row At in TableView
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotesCell", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell
        
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
        cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
                
        let dict = arrayNotes[indexPath.section]

        let info = dict.info[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.lblNotesTitle.text = info.notesTitle
        cell.lblNotesDescription.text = info.notesDescription
        cell.lblNotesDate.text = info.notesDate
        
        return cell
        
    }

// MARK: - Button Create New Note Event

 func createNewNotesButton(_ sender: UIButton){
        
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "NotesStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
        
        let createNewNotesVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateNewNotesVC") as! CreateNewNotesVC
        createNewNotesVC.delegate = self
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(createNewNotesVC, animated: true)
        
    }


// MARK: - Create New Notes Protocol Conformance
    
    func passNewNotesModel(object: NotesModel) {
                
        for item in arrayNotes{
            if item.groupName == object.groupName{
                print("same section")
                var ogInfo = item.info
                let addedInfo = object.info
                
                ogInfo.append(contentsOf: addedInfo)
                print("ogInfo after appending --> \(ogInfo)")
                
                arrayNotes.append(NotesModel(groupName: item.groupName, info: ogInfo)) 

// I want to append rows in section that already exist on ViewController, there is already 3 sections with different number of rows but this doesn't append in respective section but creates new section every time

            }else{
                print("different section")

                arrayNotes.append(object) 

// and if section doesn't exist here on ViewController then create new section and add rows in it. but this adds multiple sections

            }
        }
        
        self.tableViewNotes.reloadData()
        
    }
```

2. this is my CreateNewNotesVC(SecondVC)

   // MARK: - Protocol Create New Notes for NotesModel

   protocol CreateNewNotesModel {
   func passNewNotesModel(object: NotesModel)
   }

   var newNotesModel: NotesModel!

   var delegate: CreateNewNotesModel?

here i have textFields and "SUBMIT" button, on "SUBMIT" button click, pass NotesModel object and popView to firstVC and tableView on firstVC should be updated with newly created model object.

also there is one drop down menu here from which i have to select note's group name say there are 6 different group names, which represents section in tableView, if i choose "ABC" group name from drop down menu then on ViewController(firstVC) data should be append in "ABC" section in tableView, if i choose "OMG" group name from drop down which doesn't exist on ViewController(firstVC), then new section should be created.

```
// MARK: - Button Submit Event

@IBAction func btnSubmit_Event(\_ sender: Any) {

var info = [NotesInfo]()

info.append(NotesInfo(groupName: txtSelectGroup.text ?? "", image: ImageString, notesTitle: txtNotesTitle.text ?? "", notesDescription: txtNotesDescription.text ?? "", notesDate: txtNotesDate.text ?? ""))
    
    newNotesModel = (NotesModel(groupName: txtSelectGroup.text ?? "", info: info))

    delegate?.passNewNotesModel(object: newNotesModel)
    
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

   }
```

i want to append data in respective sections, my code is generating section every time due to for loop, i have no idea how to append data in respective section, any help would be really appreciated ! Thank You.

```
// UPDATE: as per WeyHan Ng suggestion:

for item in arrayNotes{
            var ogInfo = item.info
            let addedInfo = object.info

            ogInfo.append(contentsOf: addedInfo)
            print("ogInfo after appending --> \(ogInfo)")

            if item.groupName == object.groupName{

                print("same section")

                let index = arrayNotes.firstIndex(where: { $0.groupName == object.groupName})!
                print(index)

                arrayNotes[index].info = ogInfo // this is solved

            }else{
                print("different section")
                arrayNotes.append(object) // ISSUE: appending more than one section every time
            }

        }

        self.tableViewConsultantMilestones.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in your `passNewNotesModel(object: newNotesModel)` method,  You are doing the following:

```
Iterate through every element in 'arrayNotes' as 'item'.
  If the element 'groupName' of 'item' matches the 'groupName' of 'object'
    Make a copy of 'item.info' as 'ogInfo'
    Make a copy of 'object.info' as 'addedInfo'

    Append 'addedInfo' to 'ogInfo'

    Append 'ogInfo' to 'arrayNotes'

  Else
    Append 'object' to 'arrayNotes'
  End if
End loop
```

So, for `arrayNotes` with N elements your code appends `object` of N-1 times and append 1 time `ogInfo + addedInfo`

What you need to do is to is:

```
Find index of the element with 'groupName' equal to 'object.groupName'
If found
  Replace 'arrayNotes[foundIndex]' with 'arrayNotes[foundIndex] + object.info'

Else
  Append 'object' to 'arrayNotes'
End if
```

Hint: you can use `first(where: (String) throws -> Bool)` method to find the element in `arrayNotes` and use it's return value to replace the element.

Comment: Thank u for your response, your suggestion worked for "if" part, but "else" part is appending more than one section every time because of for loop, I have updated my question with your suggested code

Comment: But in my answer, there is no for loop. You just use the first-where function to find the index where element.groupName is equal to groupName. The if-else statement is after the first-where call. See my comment in your answer.

Comment: yes ! thank u, understood your point

Answer (score 0):

// UPDATE

// Below code worked for me

```
 // MARK: - Create New Notes Protocol Conformance

func passNewNotesModel(object: NotesModel) {

let filteredDict = self.arrayNotes.filter({$0.groupName == object.groupName})

if filteredDict.count > 0 {
    
    // add rows in that particular section
    
    for indexValue in arrayNotes.enumerated() {
        
        if indexValue.element.groupName == filteredDict.first?.groupName {
            
            if let obj = filteredDict.first {
                
                var ogInfo = obj.info
                let addedInfo = object.info
                ogInfo.append(contentsOf: addedInfo)
                arrayNotes[indexValue.offset].info = ogInfo
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
} else {
    
    // add new section
    arrayNotes.append(object)
    
}

}
```

Comment: You use the filter function instead of the first-where function I've suggested. The filter function will not keep the index to the element found to match object. Therefore you need to have a for loop to find the object again. Very inefficient. My suggestion uses the first-where function that returns the position of the element matched. Using the index returned from the first-where function, you directly update the element in the array. There is no need to write another for loop to find the element again.

Answer (score 0):

// UPDATE

// WeyHan Ng suggestion worked for me:

```
 // MARK: - Create New Notes Protocol Conformance

 func passNewNotesModel(object: NotesModel) {

let index = arrayNotes.firstIndex(where: { $0.groupName == object.groupName})
print(index ?? 0)

if index != nil{
    var ogInfo = arrayNotes[index ?? 0].info
    let addedInfo = object.info
    ogInfo.append(contentsOf: addedInfo)
    arrayNotes[index ?? 0].info = ogInfo
}else{
    arrayNotes.append(object)
}

}
```